# Updating CPropertyPage on tab selection

Tags: c++, tabs, mfc, auto-update, cpropertysheet

I am looking for the best way to update a CPropertyPage once it is clicked.  Currently, my pages receive it's information during `OnInitDialog()`.  However, when the user does something on page one, it can effect what is on page two.

The only solution I can think to use is an "Update" button.  Once the button is clicked, the page refreshes its information by calling the same functions that take place during `OnInitDialog()`.  Is there an event that occurs when the user clicks on a different CPropertyPage of a CPropertySheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an "Update" button is poor design because it requires the user to force the update.  Instead, you should look to maintain the state of the values that could cause the update.  This can be done in a structure or class object that can then be made accessible to [CPropertyPage::OnSetActive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zd196y3.aspx) of the page that needs the updated values.  *OnSetActive* is called just before the page is to be made the active one.  It's your opportunity to update values on the page before it displays.

Comment: Thank you @rrirower .  You are the CProperty-Master!